# Replace a file from host to container with mounted volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to change some configuration files required for application setup but do not want to change the original config file in the source code.

The path to the original config file is `/usr/src/app/env_configs/local_db_setup.rb`

The way I try to achieve this is in my Dockerfile

```
cp <path of new config on host>/local_db_setup.rb /usr/src/app/env_configs/
```

However, I perceive that due to my volume mounted in `docker-compose.yml`, the Copy is not taking place or overridden.

```
volumes:
-.:/usr/src/app
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If you bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount.](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container) So any existing contents at `/usr/src/app` inside the container are shadowed.

If you want to copy the new config file during image build time as mentioned in your question, you can copy it to a different directory in the image(`/tmp/config/`) and move it to correct location (`/usr/src/app/env_configs/`) using an entrypoint script which does the move first and then starts the actual entrypoint.

Instead you can also directly mount the config file from host machine if that is okay.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean when you say 'directly mount the config file'?

Comment: You can create the `env_configs/` directory with config file inside the host directory(eg: `host_dir`) that you want to mount into the container and when you mount it using `host_dir/:/usr/src/app`, then `/usr/src/app/env_configs/` inside container should have the configuration.

Comment: Ah, I see, I do not want to overwrite these configs. Nevertheless, the entrypoint approach is the one for me I suppose.